# Attribute jsx not allowed here warning - styled JSX in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, jsx, webstorm

[image]

I cannot figure out how to stop showing warnings in WebStorm about styled JSX attributes.

I have added styled-jsx to babel and ESLint config.

JavaScript language version is set to ECMAScript 6 (supports JSX). Other JSX attributes like `className` are not showing warnings.

---

**Edit:** I've already installed the react template plugin and it doesn't fix the issue here.

How to have inspection not show warnings for these JSX style attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding `styled-jsx` as a library under Languages and Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries > Download

Now the attributes are no longer showing warnings.

[image]

Comment: doesn't work without Typescript installed

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried by installing React-Template plugin?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've installed that plugin and it is active. It fixed most of the syntax warnings, but not the one in my question.